# Generating closing tag for empty elements using XMLBeans

Tags: xsd, marshalling, unmarshalling, xmlbeans

I have following xsd :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="employee" type="employeeType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="employeeType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
      <xs:element type="xs:int"  name="age"/> 
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="address"/>          
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

If i set value **only** for Name i.e

```
 EmployeeDocument request=EmployeeDocument.Factory.newInstance();
 EmployeeType emp=EmployeeType.Factory.newInstance();
 emp.setName("Name");
 request.setEmployee(emp);
```

Then XMLBeans generating following xml:

```
<employee>
    <name>Name</name>
</employee>
```

But i need a following kind of xml to be generated ,means closing tags `</>` for all elements whose values are not set in program :

```
<employee>
    <name>Name</name>
    <age/>
    <address/>
</employee>
```

well , XMLBeans generating `<address/>` if i set an empty string i.e `emp.setAddress("");`

Is there any way we could meet such requirement using XMLBeans , without setting empty string.

And more over we could not set empty string for element age which is of type int .

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The XMLSchema way to do this is add `nillable="true"` to your age and address elements.  When you recompile the xsd with XMLBeans, you will have `.setNilAge()` and `.setNilAddress()` methods.  The generated xml will look like:

```
<employee xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <name>Name</name>
  <age xsi:nil="true"/>
  <address xsi:nil="true"/>
</employee>
```

By the way, it is better to build up your document using `.addNewEmployee()` instead of `.setEmployee()` if possible.  This avoids copying the employee instance into the document which is more expensive.